# Visual Studio 2012 random debugger startup failure: Unable to start program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a managed startup project and quite often when I press F5 the Visual Studio complains with dialog "Unable to start program '...\test.exe'" (no additional information). The process test.exe is actually started in the background but when I try to attach the debugger to it, VS complains that debugger is already attached. To be able to debug again I have to manually kill the test.exe process and restart the VS. I run VS as Administrator. Thanks!

Important information:

1. Running on Windows Server 2008 x64.
2. Application is x64.
3. Running VS as Administrator.

Comment: Did you have any further hints than a "Unable to start program" ?

Comment: As I pointed with "no additional information" - unfortunately no.

Comment: Have taken a look at Output ?

Comment: not a duplicate, and nothing in debug output about test.exe

Comment: @KyorCode Not a duplicate. VS is SNAFU manifested in random behavior. I have the a similar problem in VS 2010 running Windows Forms: It will launch in Debug mode OK for a while, then will refuse to continue launching in Debug (no problem launching in Release) **until I reboot my PC**. If this isn't a bug in VS, I don't know what a bug is. +1 to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared (almost completely) after uninstalling and installing the latest VS2012Pro. I had the same message again but just a few times since that.

Comment: I'm still getting this randomly in VS2013 debug mode. Restarts make it go away for a while...

Comment: I just want to add that this is still happening in VS 2013 in 64 bit mode. No problems in 32 bit mode. It seems to be a major bug

Comment: Same here, it looks the process keeps in a "suspended" state. You can manualy "resume" the process with sysinternals process explorer. However debugging doesn't work, because the debugger has already dettached.